# jQuery Tools: Scrollable / Navigator items flowing out of the container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-float

I'm using jQuery Tool's Scrollable with the Navigator plugin.

Some useful links:

- [Documentation for Scrollable](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html)
- [Documentation for Scrollable's Navigator plugin](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/navigator.html)
- [Standalone demo of Navigator](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/plugins/navigator.htm)

**And most importantly: [a demo of how I'm using Scrollable/Navigator](http://qortiz.redio.de/).**

Works well so far. But I'd like for it to behave differently:

I want the images (or rather, generally speaking, elements in `<div class="items">`) to "flow" right out of the Scrollable container (`<div class="slider">` in my demo) until the right border of the browser window.
People with higher screen resolutions would obviously see more pictures/items flowing out of the container than people with lower resolutions.

In case this sounds confusing (which it probably does), here's some pictures:

- [first image, **normal**](http://oi55.tinypic.com/1zz6d0n.jpg)
- [first image, **how it should be**](http://oi52.tinypic.com/25hq04k.jpg)

...then when you click on the right arrow to scroll to the next picture:

- [second image, **normal**](http://oi56.tinypic.com/33l1083.jpg)
- [second image, **how it should be**](http://oi51.tinypic.com/21japlj.jpg)

Okay, I guess that's about it. Thanks for reading this far!

Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATED 3** - *( Tested in IE6, IE7, IE8, Chrome, Firefox )*

*DEMO:*

http://so.devilmaycode.it/jquery-tools-scrollable-navigator-items-flowing-out-of-the-container/

*CSS:*

*( Representing the things to change / add )*

```
*{margin:0;padding:0}
body,html{overflow:hidden}
#wrapper {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden
}
.slider {
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 3000px;
    overflow: hidden
}
.slider .items {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 3000px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1
}
a.browse{z-index:2}
a.prev{left:10px}
a.next{background-position:0 -30px;left:460px}
#navi{margin:10px 0 0 50px}
```

Comment: Wow, I have to admit this is a lot more elegant than my solution ;) However, buttons seem to disappear in IE. I have no idea if my solution does work in IE btw, as I have only tried it in Firebug. Anyway, you may want to take a look at that. When it works, you certainly have my upvote.

Comment: My pleasure, I like the way we now have 3 different approaches on here. One more thing: I think your wrapper should be 500px so as not to obscure the "navi" circles, and also said circles should have their container pushed a little to the right.

Comment: @Spiny Norman - tnx completely forget the #navi, fixed now! lol

Comment: @Julie - ugh, now I have to try it out :p (also, thanks for testing :) )

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the main thing (#wrapper) to be centered.

Comment: @user367217 - what do you mean with centered, see the update and let me knpw! ;)

Comment: @Julie Rokk: Centered as in in the center of the screen, horizontally.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I find this as hard to believe as anyone, but this seems to work in Chrome at least:

css:

```
body, html {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slider {
    width: 6000px;
}
.next {
    left: 560px;
}
```

And that's it. I'm going to see if it works in other browsers as well now.

EDIT:
Of course, IE6/7 screw it up, *except when there's a #hash in the url*. Figures. Add the code below to make it work everywhere, centered and all.

```
div#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -300px;
}
```

Here's a link:
http://nullenenenen.nl/12345_2.html

EDIT 2:

To make sure you can enjoy your content as long as possible when risizing your browser, add this as well:

```
div#wrapper {
    top: 10%;
    margin-top: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I can't edit the online version from where I am now, so "edit 2" has not been applied to 12345_2.html yet.

Comment: Wow, you were right, but I didn't see it at first: it does work when there's a #hash in the URL... It now works through applying some position: absolute; violence.

Comment: Thanks. Problem though: the `overflow: hidden;` removes both scrollbars, so if e.g. the browser window is resized, the content will just disappear (clipped). Is there no way around this?

Comment: Well, you could add `overflow-y: auto`, but that's not accepted by older browsers. You could also set the `#wrapper` to `margin-top: 0; top: 10%;` (or something). That way, you'll see more of the content when you resize.

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of those `width` property in the CSS on `slider` class, and specify `margin-left` instead to make it has some space on the left of window, just like in your demo. But obviously you need to adjust the navigation (the anchor with class `next browse` so it position absolute by left (not right as in your CSS). And for the navigation below the slider, you just need to adjust it the same as the slider by adding `margin-left` with the same value.

Comment: Maybe I don't get it here. You want it to centered? But in the same time you want the slider items to "flow" right out of the Scrollable container until the right border of the browser window? Basically if you want it like that than it already can't be called "centered" but instead call it "right" aligned.

Comment: Well, the "main layout/container" will still be centered, only the items in the slider will flow out of the container.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, assuming you want the numbers to show up on the right but not on the left and this is the only thing you want to show on the page, your main problem is that you can't have `overflow: visible` on the right but not on the left. How about faking it like this:

add html (add a div before slider):

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="smokescreen"></div> <!-- added this -->
    <div class="slider">
```

add css:

```
.slider {
    overflow: visible;
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.smokescreen {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: -2000px; 
    width: 2000px; 
    height: 400px; 
    background: black; 
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Here is a link: http://nullenenenen.nl/12345.html#

Now, the additional `div` moves with the wrapper, obscuring everything to the left of it. Of course you can alter the "2000px" as you see fit.

Comment: Hey, welcome back :) Have a look at my other answer, it works better than this one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the best I could come up with (with very little impact to the code you already have present).

*CSS Changes*

```
/* Keep original CSS, just add these to their groups */
html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
}

.slider {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

*Javascript Change*

```
// Add in the .Scrollable({ ... }) tag
onSeek: function(o,e){
  $('.items').children().css('visibility','');
  $('.items').children().filter(':lt('+e+')').css('visibility','hidden');
}
```

Granted, it's not instant (like it's scrolling under an object or off-screen) but it achieves what you're trying to do with very minimal effort.

**EDIT**

Added the overflow-x to remove horizontal scroll bar at the bottom. Observed to work in:

- FF4 (beta)
- FF3 (v3.6.13)
- IE8 (v8.0.7600.16385)
- Chorome (v8.0.552.224)

Comment: This results in a huge horizontal scrollbar though :/

Comment: Not here, works flawless. Full-screen (normal browser): http://fiddle.jshell.net/VGrWX/2/show/light/ -- jsfiddle page: http://www.jsfiddle.net/VGrWX/3/ -- Also, works on FF, IE, Chrome. Never tested Opera or others though.

Comment: My apologies, use these links: http://fiddle.jshell.net/VGrWX/4/ & http://fiddle.jshell.net/VGrWX/4/show/light/ (minor update to CSS to show your #nav bullets. Given this is an off-linked site, I had to explicitly reference your images [hope you don't mind :grin:])

Comment: Still has a huge horizontal scrollbar (maybe you didn't see it at first because the slider is really tiny).

Comment: Simple fix, apply `overflow-x: hidden !important;` inside the `html,body{}` style. Please see http://fiddle.jshell.net/VGrWX/5/ & http://fiddle.jshell.net/VGrWX/5/show/light/ -- BTW, that appears to work in FF4, FF3, IE8 & Chrome8 (if you have any other browsers, please try those too)

Answer (score 1):

One question, is it essential that the .slider element is centered on screen?

if not you can do something like this:

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 100px 0 0 100px;
    width: auto; // or rather remove the width 
}
.slider {
    width: auto; // or 100%, or remove the width
}
a.next {
    left: 560; // remove the right: 10px;
}
```

I think that about covers it. The only problem is that you define how much space there is on the left side with the left margin of #wrapper element.

Comment: Yeah it should be centered, unfortunately. Thanks anyway though.